# connecting to database using RMySQL and .my.cnf file in R

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to connect to my company's MySQL database from R, but am not allowed to keep the username and password in my code, and so I created a .my.cnf file. My .my.cnf file looks like this (password, dbname and hostnames adjusted):

```
[dbname]
username = admin-read
port = 3306
password = mypassword
host = myhost.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
datasets = dbname
```

Then I run the following code in R to (try to) connect to the database, and receive the following error:

```
rmysql.settingsfile <- "~/.my.cnf"
rmysql.db <- "dbname"
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, default.file = rmysql.settingsfile, group = rmysql.db, user = NULL, password = NULL)

Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'myname'@'ec2-publicip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
```

It is a pain that this isn't working. Initially, I had written my code with the username and password passed to the dbConnect() function, as so, and connecting to the database worked fine:

```
my_connection <- dbConnect(
  MySQL(),
  user="admin-read",
  dbname="dbname",
  host="myhost.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
  password="mypassword"
)
```

... and connection in this way worked okay.

Any help with the error, and how I could fix this, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your *.conf file has all the syntax allright:

```
[wp]
user=wordpress
port=3306
password=xxxxxxxxxx
host=127.0.0.1
database=test
```

Comment: Where can we find documentation on valid *.conf file syntax?

Answer (score 0):

in my case i used "" for all the options inside the file .cnf

```
[wp]
user="wordpress"
port="3306"
password="xxxxxxxxxx"
host="127.0.0.1"
database="test"
```